# Is it appropriate to compare normalized data between treatment groups if each is not different compared to it's respective control?

Tags: interpretation

I am not sure if our results are meaningful.  We are comparing the molecular effects of blast injury to the brain.  We have 2 different blast/control groups:

1. The animals receive a single blast, with their control group in which the animals receive the same treatment without the blast (e.g., anesthesia, etc.).
2. The animals receive 3 blasts, 1 hour apart, with their control group.

N=10 in both blast and control groups per treatment.

When we compare the data (ANOVA with either Tukey's or Bonferoni), p>0.05 for blast vs. control for both groups and when comparing the 1x vs 3x controls.  But when we normalize the data to its respective control and then compare the 1x vs 3x blast p<0.05.

My question is, if neither treatment is different compared to its control does it make sense to compare between the blast groups?

Also is the result meaningful for the 1x blast to be significantly different to the 3x blast if neither is different compared to its control?

Comment: Welcome to CV! I have made some edits to your post for clarity (let me know if I unintentionally changed the meaning). What do you mean by "normalize?" Generating a *t*-score from your measurements, or performing some kind of power transformation?

Comment: Thank you!  To normalize, basically, the mean of blast group is divided by the mean of its respective control so they can be compared since the conditions for each group is different eg time under anesthesia.

Comment: It is still unclear to me why there are two separate control groups rather then: control, single blast, three blasts. Apart from that, what made you decide to divide by the control groups' means rather than subtract the control groups' means?

Comment: There are 2 control groups because there are different conditions in the treaments: group 1: animals were anesthetized and received one blast 17 psi. Group one controls were anesthetized once but not blasted. Group 2 were anesthetized and received a 17 psi blast and returned to its cage to recover. One and two hours later this was repeated so each animal was both anesthetized and blasted 3 times. Group 2 controls were anesthetized 3 times an hour apart to match the treatment group. Anesthesia can affect some of the molecular markers in the brain that we are looking at.

Comment: Does subtracting make more sense here?